# Excel Formula overly complex

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a formula that builds a string with If statements, CONCATENATE, and text formulas.
My problem is that the formula's getting extremely larger than I ever wanted it.

My formula first looks to see if a cell if blank

```
=IF(I3="","",Else)
```

The Second part is to check if the letters "DKB" is in the H cell

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*DKB*",$H3)),True,False)
```

The Third is if the duration (Cell F) has 0 hrs do not include (HH)

```
=IF(TEXT(F3,"HH")<>"00",CONCATENATE(TEXT(F3,"hh\h\r mm\m\i\n"),CONCATENATE(TEXT(F3,"mm\m\i\n"))
```

The Fourth one is if the are 0 min don't include min selection

```
=IF(TEXT(F3,"MM")<>"00",CONCATENATE(Text(F3,"HH:MM")),CONCATENATE(Text(F3,"HH"))
```

If I were to write all the ways this could get played out I would have a total of 10 IF's. I want a simple way to write for each option without having to write out each answer. I have a partial code but doesn't include the minute portion. Is there a better way to do this? as you can see me using only if statements I'm not an expert.

Here's a picture to demonstrate my sample data and sample output
[image]

If we could have a variable for the first part ie:10-17 to 9:10 PM

2nd variable for duration

3rd variable for DKB

Would this be possible

Comment: Why not include hours and minutes on every return? Having a mix of both can be very confusing if one cell shows only `09` to be meant as hours and another cell also shows only `09` to be meant as minutes.  With hh:mm there's no ambiguity and the two results would be `09:00` and `00:09`

Comment: I separate that portion because the F column is duration and I want it to be formatted in 09hr 09min not 09:09

Comment: With a text function format of `"hh\h\r mm\m\i\n"` that will return the desired format as `09hr 00min` and `00hr 09min`, would that be acceptable? (or `09hr 09min` if the result was `09:09`)

Comment: modified the code to show this and would that hide 00hr or show it

Comment: Also, what does the second check actually do with the DKB check? If it fails the DKB check, then should the end result be blank?

Comment: Basically, I think we need sample data and expected results before we can proceed

Comment: @tigeravatar modified my question - could we use variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126261/discussion-between-brett-nelson-and-tigeravatar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for:

```
=IF(I3="","",TEXT(A3,"mm-dd-yyyy")&" On-Site "&TEXT(E3,"hh:mm AM/PM")& "- "&TEXT(G3,"hh:mm AM/PM")&" "&TEXT(F3,"hh\h\r mm\m\i\n")&IF(COUNTIF(H3,"*DKB*"),MID(H3,4,20),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(I3="","",TEXT(A3,"mm-dd-yyyy")&" On-Site "&TEXT(E3,"hh:mm AM/PM")&"- "&TEXT(G3,"hh:mm AM/PM")&" "&IF(COUNTIF(F3,"*:00:*"),TEXT(F3,"hh\h\r"),IF(COUNTIF(F3,"00:*:*"),TEXT(F3,"mm\m\i\n"),TEXT(F3,"hh\h\r mm\m\i\n"))&IF(COUNTIF(H3,"*DKB*"),MID(H3,4,20),""))))
```

This Will Make is so It won't show 00hr or 00min